# Computing the area bounded by cubic curves in the first quadrant

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $a > b > 0$, $\alpha > \beta > 0$. I am asked to compute the area in the first quadrant bounded by the curves $x^3 = a^2 y$, $x^3 = b^2 y$, $y^3 = \alpha^2 x$, $y^3 = \beta^2 x$.

What is a good way to approach this? I was thinking perhaps I could find a way to transform a rectangle in the plane to the region via some function $\textbf{G} : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, and then I could calculate the the integral with a change of variables over the rectangle instead. But I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: There are four points of intersections, determining three intervals of integration.

Comment: @Lucian: Yeah but is there a better way that doesn't have to involve that algebraic tedium?